# Запуск утилиты из php скрипта

Tags: php

Если запускать внешнее приложение или сценарий при помощи функций `exec` или `system`, то они ожидают завершения выполнения вызванного приложения и лишь потом возвращают управление в сценарий.
Как можно запустить приложение и не ожидать его завершения?

Comment: То что надо. Спасибо всем за ответы! :)

Answer (score 2):

Чтение документации у нас, видимо, не в чести. Читаем [доки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php), смотрим комменты, делаем поиск по документу по слову **background**. Обращаем внимание на то, что способ запуска программ в фоне различается для Windows и Linux. Не забываем перенаправлять поток вывода внешней программы в файл или `/dev/null`, иначе он будет выводиться в текущий документ.

Answer (score 2):

Перенаправить вывод в dev/null и сообщить приложению или сценарию запускаться в фоне:
`exec("task.php > /dev/null 2>/dev/null &");`